# How to read characters in a string in java

Tags: java, string

I'm new in java, so sorry if this is an obvious question.

I'm trying to read a string character by character to create tree nodes.
for example, input `"HJIOADH"`
And the nodes are `H  J  I  O  A  D  H`

I noticed that

```
char node = reader.next().charAt(0);  I can get the first char H by this
char node = reader.next().charAt(1);  I can get the second char J by this
```

Can I use a cycle to get all the characters? like

```
for i to n
    node = reader.next().charAt(i)
```

I tried but it doesn't work.

How I am suppose to do that?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input your nodes as capital letters without space and '/' at the end");
        int i = 0;
    char node = reader.next().charAt(i);
    while (node != '/') {

```
        CreateNode(node); // this is a function to create a tree node
        i++;
        node = reader.next().charAt(i);

    }
```

Comment: Post your full code because we don't know what reader is?

Comment: Get the characters in array using `char[] array = "HJIOADH".toCharArray();` Explore the methods present in `String` class itself.

Comment: Thanks for everybody! I got it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You only want to `next()` your reader once, unless it has a lot of the same toke nrepeated again and again.

```
String nodes = reader.next();
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I want! Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote you up..

Answer (score 3):

as Braj mentioned you can try `reader.toCharArray()` and to then you can easily use the loop

```
char[] array = reader.toCharArray();
for (char ch : array) {
    System.out.println (ch);
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this gonna work, but I don't want to consume extra space for that.

Comment: @Ahaha what do you mean by extra space ?

Comment: If anything you're using less space with this implementation

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for another solution:

```
    String anyString = "anystring";
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(anyString);
    sn.useDelimiter("");

    while (sn.hasNext()){
        char c = sn.next().charAt(0);
        // logic for chars...
    }
```