# How to bold a section of a string in Java on an Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, simpleadapter

I am passing the string via an ArrayList Hashmap. My code is as follows;

```
        Adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), myList,
                R.layout.content, new String[]{ "TA", "IA"},
                new int[]{R.id.ta, R.id.ia});
        listview.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        listview.setAdapter(Adapter1);
```

What gets passed is really the values of "TA" and "IA" keys of the Hashmap. They go straight to TextViews at R.id.ta, R.id.ia.

How do I bold only a section of that text. For example, it contains a number, and I want to bold only that number. (I don't want to bold R.id.ta, R.id.ia fully)

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making part of a string bold in textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850822/making-part-of-a-string-bold-in-textview)

Comment: I can't use StyleSpan like it's mentioned in the link because my values are in an ArrayList Hashmap which get set via a SimpleAdapter. Did you read the question?

Comment: you need to get number from your string and make that number bold using Spannable string

Comment: First, I don't know how to get the string to a new string. That is the crux of this question. Then I can think of editing the string.

Comment: get the number from string like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306135/how-to-read-characters-in-a-string-in-java

Comment: Since there are other suggestions on how to achieve what you want if you can get the String, I think your question should be more focused on getting the exact String from key values somehow.. Consider editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String sourceString = "<b>" + boldText + "</b> " + normalText;
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));
```

Comment: First, I don't know how to get the string to a new string. That is the crux of this question. Then I can think of editing the string.

Comment: Why downvote, did you know how to bold specific string?

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using custom layout. Then you can do something like below

There are two methods to make some text bold

1. HTML text
2. SpannableStringBuilder

A useful post for this can be found at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold). If you want to highlight/bold only number then this can be acheived using Regex. Useful example for the same [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015186/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string)

Comment: I can't use these because my values are in an ArrayList Hashmap which get set via a SimpleAdapter.

Comment: Have you checked the 2nd option i.e. SpannableStringBuilder. It will give you the string after all which you can pass in your string array.

**SpannableStringBuilder str = new SpannableStringBuilder("Your awesome text");
str.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), INT_START, INT_END, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);**

Comment: First, I don't know how to get the string to a new string. That is the crux of this question. Then I can think of editing the string.

Comment: if you don't know how to implement the same , then why you downvote my answer??